# Hide toggle link for logout in header magento2

Tags: magento2, login, header

Once logged in customer name will be shown with arrow beside it.

After clicking arrow a logout link appears.

My requirement is to remove that click action.

Directly can we show Logout link in header when customer is logged in?

Can anybody help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can Override

> **module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml** 
>   in theme folder.

```
<?php if($block->customerLoggedIn()): 

            echo $this->getLayout()
              ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink')
              ->setTemplate('Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml')
              ->toHtml();

endif; ?>
```

Paste only above code in phtml file.

Comment: yes, this will remove the welcome message but an arrow will be shown once cliked logout link appears.

Comment: @Manjunath Please check updated answer.

Comment: I hope you are not cleared with my question. what the above snippet will do can u please brief me?

Comment: @Manjunath please Override **customer.phtml** and remove code between condition. Hope it will work for you.